# How to get the value of a value as a key of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm not sure if this has been asked before since I also don't know how to word it:

So for example i have a given dictionary with keys and values:

```
d = {[ 0 : 1, 2, 3], [1 : 2, 3, 4], [2: 5, 6, 7]}
```

and I want to show that 1 is a key and is also a value, thereby getting to the conclusion that
0 is connected to the value of 1. like [0:[2,3,4], 2, 3] or something like that.

And I would be doing this for a large amount of keys, each with multiple values.

Is this possible? And how would I code that? By the way, I'm very new to Python so please take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
d = { 0 : (1, 2, 3) , 1 : (2, 3, 4), 2: (5, 6, 7)}
for key in d.keys():
    for val in d[key]:
        try:
            d[key]+=d[val]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

gives

```
>>> d
{0: (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 2: (5, 6, 7)}
```

If you want unique values then add `d[key] = tuple(set(d[key]))` to the end of the `for key in d.keys()` loop.

gives

```
>>> d
{0: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 2: (5, 6, 7)}
```

ps: `d = {[ 0 : 1, 2, 3], [1 : 2, 3, 4], [2: 5, 6, 7]}` is not valid python!

edit: see comments.

```
d = { 0 : [1, 2, 3] , 1 : [2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7]}
for key in d.keys():
    orig_vals=d[key]
    new_vals=[]
    for val in orig_vals:
        try:
            new_vals+=d[val]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    d[key] = list(set(new_vals)-set(orig_vals))
```

gives

```
>>> d
{0: [4, 5, 6, 7], 1: [5, 6, 7], 2: []}
```

If you want to avoid clearing values that were not linked to other keys, e.g. [5,6,7] in 2, then change the last line to

```
if new_vals:
        d[key] = list(set(new_vals)-set(orig_vals))
```

which gives

```
>>> d
{0: [4, 5, 6, 7], 1: [5, 6, 7], 2: [5, 6, 7]}
```

edit 2: see comments.

```
d = { 0 : [1, 2, 3] , 1 : [2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7]}
for key in d.keys():
    orig_vals=d[key]
    new_vals=[]
    count = 0
    for val in orig_vals:
        try:
            new_vals+=d[val]
            count+=1
            if count >= yournumberhere: break
        except KeyError:
            pass
    d[key] = list(set(new_vals)-set(orig_vals))
```

Comment: oh yes thank you! This is definitely along the lines of what I wanted to do! Yeah, I just realized my mistake with the dictionary, thank you also for pointing that out. Is it also possible to change the value of the key such that it is only the value of the values? (this terminology is quite confusing haha)

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by value of the values?  Multiple keys per value?

Comment: Oh, do you mean to change the assignment of `d[key]` to that of `d[val]`? e.g. `0:(1,2,3)` would go to `0:(2,3,4,5,6,7)` , or maybe to `0:[(2,3,4),(5,6,7)]` ?

Comment: errr, I think it would be changing the assignment? so 0:(1,2,3) would become 0:(4,5,6,7). I would like to remove any values that are the same with the original assignment too.

Comment: I see, tuples are immutable so we would have to use lists then.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: definitely helped me a lot, thanks very much!!! One last question, if i wanted to limit the number of times the new value is inputted, how would i do that?

Comment: You mean something like: declaring `count = 0` in the key loop and then adding `count+=1` and `if count > whatever: break` to the `try:` statement?

Comment: Uhm, sorry, I don't have any background on programming and just got introduced to Python, but yes, I think it's something like that. Could you please show me how to add it to the try: statement?

Comment: Thanks!! This is a great help!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {[ 0 : 1, 2, 3], [1 : 2, 3, 4], [2: 5, 6, 7]} this is not a valis dictionary

It will be like this:

d={0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7]}
arr=[]
for val in d.values():
       arr.extend(val)



arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

values=set(arr) #removeing repeted element from the list
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

result = [key for key in d.keys() if key in values] #will return the result
result = [1, 2]

here result = [1,2] so,1 and 2 is a key and also a vaule
```