# Creating a new dict with old keys but with subvalues

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, key-value

I'm new to programming so all help is appreciated:
Given a sample dictionary

```
d = {0 : (1, 2, 3), 1 : (2, 3, 4), 2 : (5, 6, 7)}
```

is it possible to make a new dictionary using the original keys but with the value of the keys being the sub-values of the values?
ie:

```
0: (1, 2, 3) ---> 0: (4, 5, 6, 7), 1: (5, 6, 7, val(2), val(3))...
```

So I want 2,3 to be removed since they were already included in the original values of 0 and so on.
*Also, I would like the substitution to only be done for *n* amount of times

From what I can understand, this is similar to making a subdict?

The problem is that instead of using a given dictionary like the one above with given values for each key, I have to do this over a large dictionary, so i am using

-edit-

> G = {
>
> > 0: (1,2,3)
> >
> > 1: (3,4,5)
> >
> > 2: (4,5,6)
> >
> > 3: (7,8,9)
> >
> > ...
> >
> > 150: (10,11,12)}

-end of edit-

```
k = d.keys()
v = d.values()
```

and

```
for v in k:
    print v " is connected to ", d[v]," by 1 length"
```

which is a somewhat roundabout manner to show the keys and their values

-edit-

So I would like to make a new dictionary with the new values being something like:

> G_new = {
>
> > 0: ((3,4,5),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
> >
> > 1: ((7,8,9), (values of 4), (values of 5))
> >
> > ...}

Then leave only unique values and remove values included in the old value of the key such that:

> G_new_final = {
>
> > 0: (4,5,6,7,8,9)
> >
> > 1: (7,8,9, etc.)
> >
> > ...} #until key 150

And since i'm working with a lot of numbers, i'm guessing I need some sort of function or dictionary comprehension?

-end of edit-

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, if you have keys and values then you have the equivalent of d?

Comment: Can you post the actual expected result of this transformation on `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g = {0: (1,2,3),1: (3,4,5),2: (4,5,6),3: (7,8,9)}
g2 = dict()
for key in g.keys():
    old_vals=set(g[key])
    new_vals=[]
    for val in old_vals:
        try:
            new_vals.extend(g[val])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    new_vals = tuple(set(new_vals)-old_vals)
    g2[key]=new_vals
```

gives

```
>>> g2
{0: (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 1: (8, 9, 7), 2: (), 3: ()}
```

But I don't see how this is significantly different from what I [answered previously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616688/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-value-as-a-key-of-a-dictionary/17617519?noredirect=1#comment25659822_17617519)

edit:  Interestingly this approach seems faster than the collections one?

```
import time
import random

def makeg(n):
    g=dict()
    for i in xrange(n):
        g[i] = tuple([random.randint(0,n) for _ in xrange(3)])
    return g

g=makeg(100000)

def m(g):
    g2 = dict()
    for key in g.keys():
        old_vals=set(g[key])
        new_vals=[]
        for val in old_vals:
            try:
                new_vals.extend(g[val])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        new_vals = tuple(set(new_vals)-old_vals)
        g2[key]=new_vals
    return g2

s1 = time.time()
m(g)
e1 = time.time()

from collections import defaultdict

def h(g):
    a = defaultdict(set)
    [a[x].update(g.get(y, [])) for x in g for y in g[x]]
    [a[x].difference_update(g[x]) for x in g]
    g2={x:tuple(a[x]) for x in a}
    return g2

s2 = time.time()
h(g)
e2=time.time()

mt =(e1-s1)
ht=(e2-s2)
print mt,ht,mt/ht
```

gives

```
nero@ubuntu:~/so$ python so.py 
0.556298017502 0.850471019745 0.654105789129
```

Comment: ah yes, I think the problem that came up was that the values of the keys would become mixed up since I was overwriting on the old dictionary. So I decided with making a new dictionary. But thank you though, your answer is still the one I most understood

Comment: Actually I would like to use this too, but d2 becomes

d2 = {0: (2,3,4),(5,6,7),(valueof3)...}

but is there a way to make it combine the numbers to become 
0: (4,5,6,7,valuesof3)
?

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer.

Comment: oh wow, this really works haha I'm sorry, i'm still amazed how many methods can get the same answer.

By the way, is there a way to leave out the key from being included in the values?

Comment: Do you mean that if the key were in some g[val] to exclude it from the final g[key] values?  In that case just `the_key = set([key])` after `old_vals=set(g[key])` and change the `new_vals` assignment to `new_vals = tuple(set(new_vals)-old_vals-the_key)`.

Comment: Actually I like this answer since it's still in terms that even a beginner like me can understand and explain. So thanks very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(set)
>>> d = {0: (1, 2, 3), 1: (2, 3, 4), 2: (5, 6, 7)}

#all subvalues of the values of x, no duplicate and without any value of key x
>>> [a[x].update(d.get(y, [])) for x in d for y in d[x]]
>>> [a[x].difference_update(d[x]) for x in d]

#convert it dict of tuple values
>>> {x:tuple(a[x]) for x in a}
{0: (4, 5, 6, 7), 1: (5, 6, 7), 2: ()}
>>>
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to use this without giving definite values for the sets? like I would probably like to use

{0 : set(d[0])... until k : set(d[k])}

Though I doubt what I typed is in the correct syntax.

Comment: I don't really understand. Actually I don't use any definite values for the sets. I use `defaultdict(set)`. In a comment I cannot tell clearly. But with a `defaultdict(set)`, you get a dict with a default empty set of every key in the dict. @James

Comment: ah yes, sorry, I think I was reading the unedited version. Thanks for the help!